# Typescript callback with variable parameters undefined

Tags: typescript, callback

I having trouble to pass multiple parameters through a callback function.
For some reason is one of the objects undefined.

How do i define a callback functions with multiple parameters ?

```
  public save() {
    let oldStartDate = "2019-01-01";

    let newProject = new Project();
    newProject.oldStartDate = "2018-01-01";

    this.doSomeWork(newProject, this.workFinished_Callback.bind(this), oldStartDate);
  }

  public doSomeWork(project:Project, callback: (updatedProject: Project, ...param: any[]) => any = null, ...callbackArgs: any[]) {
    //Work work..
    console.log(project); //This exists..

    callback.call(project, ...callbackArgs);
  }

  public workFinished_Callback(project:Project, oldStartDate: string) {
    console.log(project); //This is undefined..
    console.log(oldStartDate); //Shows 2018-01-01
  }
```

Comment: which one of the objects are undefined?

Comment: I've wrote comments in the code which object are undefined. Titian below answered and i solved my issue. Thanks for asking !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you use `call`. The first argument to call is the `this` parameter passed to the function, which since you bind the callback will not be accessible in the callback. You can pass `null` as the first argument and pass the project as the second argument and spread the rest of the arguments as the other arguments:

```
callback.call(null, project, ...callbackArgs);
```

A better approach would be to not use call. You can just call the function as you normally would:

```
callback(project, ...callbackArgs);
```

You can also build a fully type safe version of your code. In 3.2 `bind` is correctly typed if you enable `strictBindCallApply` (read [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028)). This means that we can use `bind` and get a correctly typed function. Pair this with tuples in rest parameters ([PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897)) and we can get the compiler to check things fully for us:

```
class Project { oldStartDate!: string }
type DoSomeworkCallbackArgs<T extends (updatedProject: Project, ...param: any[]) => any> =
    T extends (updatedProject: Project, ...param: infer A) => any ? A : []
class DD {
    public save() {
        let oldStartDate = "2019-01-01";

        let newProject = new Project();
        newProject.oldStartDate = "2018-01-01";

        this.doSomeWork(newProject, this.workFinished_Callback.bind(this), oldStartDate);
        this.doSomeWork(newProject, this.workFinished_Callback.bind(this), 0); //error
    }

    public doSomeWork<T extends null | ((updatedProject: Project, ...param: any[]) => any)>(project: Project, callback: T = null, ...callbackArgs: DoSomeworkCallbackArgs<T>) {
        //Work work..
        console.log(project); //This exists..
        if (callback) callback(project, ...callbackArgs);
    }

    public workFinished_Callback(project: Project, oldStartDate: string) {
        console.log(project); // ok now
        console.log(oldStartDate); //Shows 2018-01-01

    }
}


new DD().save()
```

Comment: Ah ! Makes sense. Thanks for the type safe verison, i will look into that more.